# Повторить строку несколько раз

Tags: java

В общем есть один метод, который принимает два параметра, например метод

```
B(int i, String str)
```

где переменная i это количество повторений str, то есть если i == 3, а str == "N", то метод вернет следующее "NNN".

Не пойму как это осуществить, не поможет мне кто?

Comment: Вам нужна книжка для новичков

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1235179/4928642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с Java 11 у строк есть встроенный метод `repeat`:

```
var s = "Qwe".repeat(3); // "QweQweQwe"
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
public String methodName(int i, String str) {
    String result = "";
    for( int u = 0; u < i; u++ ) {
        result = result + str;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `String result = "";`

Comment: Неэффективно же...

Comment: @Igor да, дкйствительно) Исправил)

Comment: @Qwertiy, ТС не просил эффективно)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а я уже ассоциацию нагуглил)

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо)